# How to stop the output of plt.plot() from appearing twice in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplot1(t,x):
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    _ = plt.plot(t,x)
    return fig1

def myplot2(t,x):
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    _ = plt.plot(t,x)
    return fig2

t = np.arange(0,6,0.01)
x = np.sin(t)
y = np.cos(t)

#calling the functions
myplot1(t,x)
myplot1(t,y)
```

As the sample code mentioned above, my objective is to plot two figures one after another. In the function definition, I have used the return statement because I would also like to save the figures if needed. The problem I am facing here is every time I call one function, for example, myplot1(t,x) two figures are coming. Could you please provide some insights on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: It has been a while since I used notebooks, but I think the function calls are automatically displaying the results, though they are not assigned to values, try using `_=myplot1(t,x)` and `_=myplot1(t,y)` instead, to assign the return value to a variable.

Comment: By adding semicolon `;`. Like this:

`myplot1(t,x);` [new line] `myplot1(t,y);`

Comment: @RufusVS Thanks for the comment. Yes, If I call like that for example, _ = myplot1(t,x) or myFig = myplot1(t,x), it shows only a single figure, but I was trying to find a solution by which I will call only myplot1(t,x) and it will give a single figure as an output.

Comment: @Aragorn Your original program was plotting once within the function and once again after function exit and return the plot.  Are you saying you want to suppress the display within the function instead?

Comment: @RufusVS Pls ignore my earlier comment.  By calling the function like myplot1(t,x); or assigning to a variable var = myplot1(t,x) will work for me. Thanks everyone.